# SQLite PRAGMA cache_size iOS

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, pragma

I am working on a Keyboard extension on iOS using Objective C where I am using SQLite. I need to understand a few concepts about SQLite which I didn't get by googling. Let me divide the question in parts.

**PART: 1**

I have come across a PRAGMA in SQLite called `PRAGMA cache_size = pages;`

The default size here is 2000 pages. **Comparing with the default**, according to my understanding,

- cache_size > 2000 means more memory usage, more speed (than default).
- cache_size < 2000 means less memory usage, less speed (than default).

Am I correct here?

---

**PART: 2**

I am trying to change the cache_size in the following way,

```
if (sqlite3_exec(sqlite3Database, [@"PRAGMA CACHE_SIZE=50;" UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully changed cache size");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Error: failed to set cache size with message %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
```

I am using this after opening the database. The following code shows it,

```
-(void)runQuery:(const char *)query isQueryExecutable:(BOOL)queryExecutable{
// Create a sqlite object.
sqlite3 *sqlite3Database;

// Set the database file path.
NSString *databasePath = [self getDbFilePath];

// Initialize the results array.
if (self.arrResults != nil) {
    [self.arrResults removeAllObjects];
    self.arrResults = nil;
}
self.arrResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


// Open the database.
BOOL openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3Database);
if(openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {

    if (sqlite3_exec(sqlite3Database, [@"PRAGMA CACHE_SIZE=50;" UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully changed cache size");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Error: failed to set cache size with message %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
    // Declare a sqlite3_stmt object in which will be stored the query after having been compiled into a SQLite statement.
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    // Load all data from database to memory.
    BOOL prepareStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database, query, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
    if(prepareStatementResult == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Check if the query is non-executable.
        if (!queryExecutable){
            // In this case data must be loaded from the database.

            // Declare an array to keep the data for each fetched row.
            NSMutableArray *arrDataRow;

            // Loop through the results and add them to the results array row by row.
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Initialize the mutable array that will contain the data of a fetched row.
                arrDataRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                // Get the total number of columns.
                int totalColumns = sqlite3_column_count(compiledStatement);

                // Go through all columns and fetch each column data.
                for (int i=0; i<totalColumns; i++){
                    // Convert the column data to text (characters).
                    char *dbDataAsChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, i);

                    // If there are contents in the currenct column (field) then add them to the current row array.
                    if (dbDataAsChars != NULL) {
                        // Convert the characters to string.
                        [arrDataRow addObject:[NSString  stringWithUTF8String:dbDataAsChars]];
                    }
                }

                // Store each fetched data row in the results array, but first check if there is actually data.
                if (arrDataRow.count > 0) {
                    [self.arrResults addObject:arrDataRow];
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // This is the case of an executable query (insert, update, ...).

            // Execute the query.
            int executeQueryResults = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
            if (executeQueryResults == SQLITE_DONE) {
                // Keep the affected rows.
                self.affectedRows = sqlite3_changes(sqlite3Database);

                // Keep the last inserted row ID.
                self.lastInsertedRowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(sqlite3Database);
            }
            else {
                // If could not execute the query show the error message on the debugger.
                NSLog(@"DB Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // In the database cannot be opened then show the error message on the debugger.
        NSLog(@"db error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
    }

    // Release the compiled statement from memory.
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}

// Close the database.
sqlite3_close(sqlite3Database);
```

}

But, when I call the method, `sqlite3_exec(sqlite3Database, [@"PRAGMA CACHE_SIZE=50;" UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL)`, it always gives `SQLITE_OK` no matter what I do.

For example, if I do `sqlite3_exec(sqlite3Database, [@"abcd bla bla" UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL)`, it returns `SQLITE_OK`!!

Why is that so?

---

**PART: 3**

I want to increase the speed of execution of my queries, but at the same time don't want to use IMDB as the size of the database is huge.

So is `PRAGMA page_size = bytes;` make any relevance in this case? If yes, then how to do it in Objective C?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks and regards.

Comment: i would urge you to use the library SQLite.swift